# Unable to connect to MySQL in CentOS VM from the host Windows machine

Tags: mysql, centos, centos6

I wanted to test my eJava application in CentOS, so I installed CentOS 6.5 in Oracle Virtual box locally in my laptop (Windows 8.1). I configured the network in the virtual machine and it is able to ping google.com as well as the host windows machine. I then installed MySQL in the CentOS VM and modified the my.cnf to edit the bind-address. Also updatd the iptables to allow input and output connections. I tried connecting to the databse from the windows host using the command

```
mysql -u supplychain -h 10.0.2.15 -P 3306 -p
```

where 10.0.2.15 is the ip address of the centos VM. I am getting the error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.2.15' (10060)
```

If I run the same command in the centos host it logs into the MySQL. Any idea how this can be fixed? I already confirmed that skip-networking is removed from the my.cnf.

Comment: does the port 3306 opened ?

Comment: I edited the iptables to allow connection via 3306. But when I tried telnet with port 3306 it is failing. Where else should I open the port?

Comment: Change settings if default port is used. Also, the IP is private. Are you sure two computers are in same network?

Comment: yes, centos VM is installed in the same windows box from where I am trying to connect. So both are in the same network.

Comment: Also it is dynamic ip by dhcp.

Comment: Server IP is by DHCP? Are you serious? Check `my.ini` to see which port is used in CentOS.

Comment: my.cnf has 3306 as the port. This is actually not a server. No one else will be using this VM for now.

Comment: I am suffering a similar problem: CentOS in a ESXi VM and trying to access from Windows. Locally server works but remotely (even if in the same network) doesn't. Turned off firewall on both sides.